# Has anyone managed to run scrapy-splash on raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, scrapy-splash

Has anyone managed to run scrapy-splash on raspberry pi? It seems that I need to build pyqt5 libraries for armv7 architecture, but I don't have experience in this field

Comment: Have you tried the raspberry pi forums? It might be a better place to ask as your question appears to be more sysadmin based than a specific programming query.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I will ask there too